# PHP insert/delete into multiple tables not working

Tags: php, mysql

I was looking for help in fixing my code.

1. First I have to insert a new breed, so I have created the form but when I enter data and click submit, the table doesn't update with changes (I think there might be something wrong with my INSERT sql statments).

[This is the table definitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibs9w.jpg)

2. I have to delete a dog from a drop down list which I have it working but my drop down list contains the description of the dog and not the name of the dog to delete.  When I click on delete it doesn't delete anything from table and table doesn't reflect the deleted item, so how can I fix this?

Any help would be great.

insert.php

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Insert a new Breed</h1>
<form action="sort4.php" method="post">
Breed Name: <input type="text" name="breedname" /><br><br>
Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" /><br><br>
Description: <input type="text" name="descr" /><br><br>
Breeder Name: <input type="text" name="breedername" /><br><br>

<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
    {

        //declare variables used to insert into mySQL database  
        $breedname=$_POST['name'];
        $phone=$_POST['phone'];
        $description=$_POST['descr'];
        $date=$_POST['date'];
        $breedername=$_POST['name']; //this is from a different table



        //echo test;
try 
{
    //sql query to insert form values into database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO breed (id, name, descr, date) VALUES   ``('".$breedname."', '".$description."', 'NOW()')"; 
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO breeder (id, phone, name) VALUES ('".$breedername."', '".$phone."')";


    $conn->exec($sql); //execute the INSERT sql statment above
    $conn->exec($sql2);

    include('AddedOwnersList.php'); 

    //echo $OwnerNum, $LastName, $FirstName, $Address, $City, $State, $Zip;

}

catch (PDOException $e)
{

echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();

} //end catch


}
?> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

sort4.php

```
<?php
include ('includes/header.html');
require ('includes/conn.php');

$sort = (isset($_GET['sort']))?$_GET['sort']:'ph';
switch ($sort)
{
    case 'dn':                   //dn is sorting on dog name
    $order_by = 'dog.name';
    break;
    case 'bn':                   //bn is sorting on breed name
    $order_by = 'breed.name';
    break;
    default:
    $order_by = 'breeder.phone';
    break;

}                        //end switch    
$sql = "select dog.name as dogname, breed.name as breedname, breed.descr as description,
    breeder.name as breedername, breeder.phone as phone from breeder, dog, breed, breed_breeder
    where dog.breed_id = breed.id and breed.id = breed_breeder.breed_id and 
    breeder.id = breed_breeder.breeder_id order by ".$order_by; 
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo '<tr>
    <td align="center"><a href="sort4.php?sort=dn"> Dog Name </a></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="sort4.php?sort=bn"> Breed Name </a></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="sort4.php?sort=ph"> Phone </a></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="sort4.php?sort=ph"> Description </a></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="sort4.php?sort=ph"> Breeder Name </a></td>
</tr>'; 

while($row = $stmt->fetch() )
{
    echo '<tr><td>' .$row['dogname'].'</td><td>' .$row['breedname'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$row['phone'].'</td><td>' .$row['description'].'</td><td>' .$row['breedername'].'</td></tr>';
}
echo "</table>";



include ('includes/footer.html');
?>
```

delete.php

```
<?php  
include ('includes/header.html');
require ('includes/conn.php');

//checks to see if delete was clicked
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{

    $id = $_POST['BreedID'];
    try
    {
        $sql = "DELETE b
              FROM breed AS b
              WHERE b.id = :breedId";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(':breedId' => $id));

    } // end try

catch (PDOException $e)
    {

    echo 'Error: '.$e->getMessage();

    } //end catch

} //end if server

echo '<center>';
echo '<h2> Select the dog breed you want to delete.</h2>';
$sql = "select name, descr from breed"; //prints sql query
echo '<form action="delete.php" method="POST">';

echo "<select name='BreedID' id=BreedID'>";

foreach($conn->query($sql) as $row) 
{
    echo '<option value = "';
    echo $row['name'];
    echo '"> ';
    echo $row['descr'];
    echo '</option>';

} // end foreach
echo '</select>';

echo '<br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete"> <br>';
echo '</form>'; //end form


$stmt = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM breed');
    echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>"; //make table to display column headers
    echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Date</th></tr>";

    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))
    {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ($row as $value)
            {
             echo "<td>{$value}</td>";
            }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';

include('includes/footer.html');    
?>
```

Comment: btw, `NOW()` is a function not a string literal, unless that's what you want to be entered in db.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using prepared statements and supply any user data as separate arguments because you have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code. Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Bookmark [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for guidance with this and other problems.